# Installing httpd through ansible roles - ok=1 instead of changed =1

Tags: apache, ansible

I have created roles to install httpd.

But the status is always 'ok=1'
instead of 'changed=1'

How should I actually install httpd and get a status of 'changed=1'

```
  master.yml->

- name: playbook
   hosts: webservers
   become: yes
   roles: 
    -tasks

   tasks.yml->

 - name: installing apache latest
    yum: 
     - name: httpd
       state: present
```

Comment: because idempotent, if httpd is already installed changed is not modified.. either show your playbook

Comment: @Frenchy I have verified if httpd got installed, but I showed a message 'service not found'. I have put the yaml script in the question. Please verify!

Comment: have you started the service like in my answer

Comment: i am pretty sure your task is not executed..you are using  a role names tasks??? its the file  main.yml which is called and not tasks.yml

Comment: On my server the role name is 'tasks' and the file inside the role which is being executed is 'main.yml' which has the task to install httpd. For the name sake I have put it that way in the question..

Comment: tasks is a reserved name..could you try to change the name of role?  either i dont see ..except i am using the module package to install apaches instead yum...  try to launch the playbook with -vvv to see other informations...

Comment: sure I will try it that way!

Answer (score 0):

have you started your service?

```
- name: service httpd started
  service:
    name: "httpd" 
    state: started
```

Comment: Its neither getting installed nor started.

Comment: What is your Linux distribution?

Comment: Amazon linux on my aws ec2 instance

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have state "present" in yum-module description.
how it works: if you have package already installed - status will be "ok", if you have not - status will be "changed".

Comment: Hey, I have tried the same code with 'present' and 'latest' states too, but there's no change with its status!

Comment: yeah, because you did fresh install, and your 'present' is 'latest' :)